# Javascript for html to bring up specific images that are initially hidden elements depending on the user input

Tags: javascript, image, html, hidden

I need to embed some javascript within a website, and what I want it to do is the following:

I want to have a set of hidden images within the website and depending on the input from user (into a query box) a certain image specified to a certain input value should appear therefore stop being invisible.

In my case I am making a timetable and I have set of 5 images, when user imputs for example "monday" the image that is set to this value (monday timetable) should appear. Please help me writing this javascript for the html document.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without showing what you've tried so far, and adding the relevant markup, this question is likely to get closed.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code to show? What is *a query box*? Do you want the user to type in "monday" or selecting it from a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data attributes to link particular elements (images) to corresponding options.

```
<select id="dow">
    <option>-- PLEASE SELECT --</option>
    <option data-target='div1'>Monday</option>
    <option data-target='div2'>Tuesday</option>
</select>
<div id="images">
    <div id="div1" class="hidden">Image for Monday</div>
    <div id="div2" class="hidden">Image for Tuesday</div>
</div>
```

You can show appropriate image using this script:

```
​$('#dow').change(function() {
    var id = $(this).find(':selected').data('target');
    $('#images > div').hide();
    $('#' + id).show();
});​​​​
```

See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s7kp4/).

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help. I will go and try this out, do a little analysis and then I will let you know whether that has helped me. Thanks